# How to count the total number of files/folders on a system?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, files, search

How can I count the number of all files/folders that exist on a system, using the command-line?

I can find it out using a GUI, simply by opening the properties window for the entire `/` folder, but it would be nice to know how to do it using the command-line.

Would I need a whole series of commands, or will just one be possible?

Comment: Do you want the number of files or the number of links?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since file / folder names can contain newlines:

```
sudo find / -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
sudo find / -type d -printf '.' | wc -c
```

This will count *any* file / folder in the current `/` directory. But as muru points out you might want to exclude virtual / other filesystems from the count (the following will exclude *any* other mounted filesystem):

```
find / -xdev -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
find / -xdev -type d -printf '.' | wc -c
```

- `sudo find / -type f -printf '.'`: prints a dot for each file in `/`;
- `sudo find / -type d -printf '.'`: prints a dot for each folder in `/`;
- `wc -c`: counts the number of characters.

Here's an example of how not taking care of newlines in file / folder names may break other methods such as e.g. `find / -type f | wc -l` and how using `find / -type f -printf '.' | wc -c` actually makes it right:

```
% ls
% touch "file
\`dquote> with newline"
% find . -type f | wc -l
2
% find . -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
1
```

If STDOUT is not a terminal, `find` will print each file / folder name literally; this means that a file / folder name containing a newline will be printed across two different lines, and that `wc -l` will count two lines for a single file / folder, ultimately printing a result off by one.

Answer (score 7):

1 method would be

```
sudo find / -type f | wc -l
sudo find / -type d | wc -l
```

(sudo to prevent accessing errors)

f for files, d for directories.

The /proc/ filesystem will error out but I do not consider those files ;)

Comment: do I need sudo? all files are like this: `find: ‘/run/lock/schroot’: Permission denied
`

Comment: yes. I got "permission denied' running it as a user.

Comment: I got 483664... not as many as I expected - does that make sense though?

Comment: I got less :D Hmmm. funny You will run into 1 problem: the /proc/ system is changing always.

Comment: @DevRobot oh you do not know who Florian is do you? ;) Check some of his high rep answers on AU.

Comment: You should use `-xdev`, or at least exclude `/proc`, `/sys`, and probably `/dev` as well.

Comment: Yup, like muru says, you don't want to count all the "virtual" files in with files on "real" (disk-backed) filesystems.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want the *total* number of objects in your filesystems, use `df -i` to count inodes.  You won't get the breakdown between directories and plain files, but on the plus side it runs near-instantly.  The total number of used inodes is something filesystems already track.

---

If you want to use one of the `find`-based suggestions, don't just run it on `/`.  Use `find -xdev` on a list of mount points generated by something like `findmnt --list -v -U -t xfs,ext3,ext4,btrfs,vfat,ntfs -o TARGET` or something.  That doesn't exclude bind mounts, though, so files under bind mounts will get counted twice.  `findmnt` [is pretty cool.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177014/showing-only-interesting-mount-points-filtering-non-interesting-types)

Also, surely there's a straightforward way to list all your "disk" mounts without having to list explicit filesystem types, but I'm not sure exactly what.

As suggested by another answer, use `find -printf . | wc -c` to avoid any possible problems counting funny characters in filenames.  Use `-not -type d` to count non-directory files.  (You don't want to exclude your symlinks, do you?)

Comment: This is a better approach than all the other answers suggesting to traverse the entire file system. A different command line tool that could also be used is `stat`. Using `stat -f /` or `df -i /` will both obtain data using the `statfs` system call, so the output from those two commands should always be consistent.

Comment: Note: `df -i` doesn't seem to work on all filesystems. e.g. on `btrfs` it shows 0 inodes.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo find / -type f | wc -l
```

will tell you the number of regular files on your system, and

```
sudo find / -type d | wc -l
```

the number of folders.

Answer (score 2):

Using `zsh`:

As `root`, for regular files:

```
files=( /**/*(.D) )
```

this will take all the regular files including the ones starting with a `.` into the array `files`, now we can simply count the number of elements of the array:

```
echo $#files
```

this will handle all the edge cases e.g. unusual file names.

Similarly for directories:

```
dirs=( /**/*(/D) )
echo $#dirs
```

Comment: @kos: but then need to manually differentiate between regular files and others..

Comment: @kos No ..then you need `/*/**/*(.D)`..also this is not right as it will ignore any file in `/`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that leverages `locatedb`:

```
locate / | wc -l
```

Advantages:

- Doesn't require sudo
- Much faster than the `find` based approaches (already pre-indexed)
- Already applies `-xdev`: i.e. skips special files: `/dev`, `/proc` etc.

Downsides:

- Not 100% accurate: includes directories, skips files under `/tmp`, may double-or-more-count files with newlines in their name, for example
- Slower than the `df -i` approach
- Reflects "last ~24 hour snapshot reality" rather than exact current state